# Show data from view in variable in layout in Joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

Here below is the code from the **view.html.php**

```
class ><><><><><><><>< extends JViewLegacy
{
    public $data;

    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null) 
    {
        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
        {
            JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
            return false;
        }
        $data = $this->data;            // This is having array object

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Here below is the code in **default.php**

```
Result View

<?php 
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The data in **default.php** is not showing any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign values from **view.html.php** you should use something like this:

```
$this->data = $data;
```

And in **default.php** you should access $data by:

```
print_r($this->data);
```

Comment: @di2sel Thanks a lot. This simple thing was missing and was messing it will like hell.. :)

Comment: This happens to all, glad i could help :)